# Windows 7 bizarrely system slows down around 15 minutes after boot

Tags: windows-7, memory, graphics-card, performance, cpu

I recently installed new hardware in my desktop rig (CPU, MB & RAM) and did a fresh Windows 7 install. The recipe for pure happiness one should think, but sadly I’ve run into a really frustrating problem.

System specs:

- **CPU:** Intel i7 6700k (No O.C.)
- **Motherboard:** [ASUS Maximus VIII Ranger](https://www.asus.com/Motherboards/MAXIMUS-VIII-RANGER/)
- **RAM:** 16GB Corsair Vengance LPX DDR4
- **GPU:** [XFX Radeon HD7950 3GB](http://benchmarkreviews.com/1787/xfx-radeon-hd-7950-black-edition-fx-795a-tdfc-video-card-review/)
- **Storage:** [500GB Corsair 850 EVO](http://www.anandtech.com/show/8747/samsung-ssd-850-evo-review)
- **OS:** Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit

Initially, Windows 7 runs smoothly and everything’s very responsive, but 15 minutes or so after start up, the system instantly slows down to a crawl. It doesn’t crash completely though. You can still do stuff but everything is agonizingly slow.

Restarting the system fixes the problem temporarily, but 15 minutes later it happens again like clockwork. Changing the color scheme to Windows 7 basic after a slow down makes the system usable, but still not as functional as on start up.

There are no obvious clues in the performance data that would suggest the cause of the problem. CPU and GPU loads are both typically ~ 0% at slow down. Same thing with disk usage. RAM usage is typically ~ 3,5 GB and VRAM ~ 280 MB. CPU temp is stable at ~ 30 °C. GPU temp ~ 60 °C.

Windows is genuine and up to date, and I have tried using both the 15.7.1 and 15.8 Beta versions of AMD’s graphics driver to no avail.

Comment: Enter into SafeMode by pressing F8 while booting. And see whether you have the same problem

Comment: The problem doesn't occur in safe mode

Comment: maybe windows tries to generate the Windows experience index. Do this on your own and look if it "fixes" it

Comment: Ran the WEI and got 7,9 across the board (apart from CPU @ 7,8), but no change. Problem sill persists.